# simplify multiple one to one paired aggregation

Tags: r, split, aggregate, melt

I'd like to calculate mean for multiple one to one paired aggregation. For example, I have a data.frame below. I'd like to calculate the mean for for column `b1` by `sym` & `a1`, and `b2` by `sym` & `a2` simultaneously.

```
   sym a1 a2 b1 b2
1   a  1  2  1  1
2   a  2  2  2  2
3   a  1  2  3  3
4   a  2  2  4  4
5   b  1  1  5  5
6   b  2  1  6  6
7   b  1  1  7  7
8   b  2  1  8  8
```

Here is my code which uses `lapply` to iterate over each pair. Is there any more efficient way than this?

```
df <- data.frame(sym=c(rep('a', 4), rep('b', 4)), a1=rep(1:2, 4), 
                 a2=rep(2:1, each=4), b1=rep(1:8), b2=rep(1:8))

tmp <- ddply(df, "sym", function(x) {

  temp.ls <- lapply(1:2, function(i) {
    t2 <- aggregate(x = x[3+i], by=x[1+i], FUN=function(.){mean(., na.rm = T)})
    colnames(t2) <- c("a", "b")
    t2
  })
  temp.all <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by=c("a"), all=T, sort=T), 
                     temp.ls)
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dplyr` makes this pretty straightforward:

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(df %>% group_by(sym, a1) %>% summarise(b1.mean=mean(b1)),
           df %>% group_by(sym, a2) %>% summarise(b2.mean=mean(b2)))

# Joining by: "sym"
# Source: local data frame [4 x 5]
# Groups: sym
# 
#   sym a1 b1.mean a2 b2.mean
# 1   a  1       2  2     2.5
# 2   a  2       3  2     2.5
# 3   b  1       6  1     6.5
# 4   b  2       7  1     6.5
```

If you want a single column for `a`, and want to fill non-appearing combinations with `NA` as in your example solution, then `left_join` is an option:

```
left_join(df %>% group_by(sym, a=a1) %>% summarise(b1.mean=mean(b1)),
          df %>% group_by(sym, a=a2) %>% summarise(b2.mean=mean(b2)),
          by=c('sym', 'a'))

# Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
# Groups: sym
# 
#   sym a b1.mean b2.mean
# 1   a 1       2      NA
# 2   a 2       3     2.5
# 3   b 1       6     6.5
# 4   b 2       7      NA
```

Hat-tip to @beginnerR for reminding me about `dplyr` `join` operations.

---

**EDIT**

In response to the comments, if you have more than two groupings, and want to join *all* the resulting tables together, then here's one way to do this:

```
# Example data
set.seed(1)
(d <- data.frame(sym=sample(letters[1:4], 10, replace=T),
           a1=sample(5, 10, replace=TRUE),
           a2=sample(5, 10, replace=TRUE),
           a3=sample(5, 10, replace=TRUE),
           b1=runif(10), b2=runif(10), b3=runif(10)))

#    sym a1 a2 a3        b1         b2         b3
# 1    b  2  5  3 0.8209463 0.47761962 0.91287592
# 2    b  1  2  3 0.6470602 0.86120948 0.29360337
# 3    c  4  4  3 0.7829328 0.43809711 0.45906573
# 4    d  2  1  1 0.5530363 0.24479728 0.33239467
# 5    a  4  2  5 0.5297196 0.07067905 0.65087047
# 6    d  3  2  4 0.7893562 0.09946616 0.25801678
# 7    d  4  1  4 0.0233312 0.31627171 0.47854525
# 8    c  5  2  1 0.4772301 0.51863426 0.76631067
# 9    c  2  5  4 0.7323137 0.66200508 0.08424691
# 10   a  4  2  3 0.6927316 0.40683019 0.87532133

L <- mapply(function(x, y) {
    grpd <- eval(substitute(group_by(d, sym, a=x), list(x=as.name(x))))
    eval(substitute(summarise(grpd, mean(y)), list(y=as.name(y))))
}, paste0('a', 1:3), paste0('b', 1:3), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)

Reduce(function(...) left_join(..., all=T), L)

# Source: local data frame [9 x 5]
# Groups: sym
# 
#   sym a  mean(b1)   mean(b2)   mean(b3)
# 1   a 4 0.6112256         NA         NA
# 2   b 1 0.6470602         NA         NA
# 3   b 2 0.8209463 0.86120948         NA
# 4   c 2 0.7323137 0.51863426         NA
# 5   c 4 0.7829328 0.43809711 0.08424691
# 6   c 5 0.4772301 0.66200508         NA
# 7   d 2 0.5530363 0.09946616         NA
# 8   d 3 0.7893562         NA         NA
# 9   d 4 0.0233312         NA 0.36828101
```

Comment: Good point @beginneR - I've incorporated that into the answer. I noticed that you suggested basically the same solution in the comments 29 sec before I posted - sorry!

Comment: Nice one! I like this approach. +1 :)

Comment: I appreciate the solution which looks excellent. Is it possible to dynamic reference column in group_by, like a[i]. Also I'd like to left_join above 10 results. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: @YYY - You can do something along [these lines](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/manipulatr/cr9PzNEtz6w), such as: `x <- 'a1'; eval(substitute(group_by(df, x), list(x=as.name(x))))`. Not sure what you mean by "above 10 results".

Comment: @jbaums Thank you again for the response. I mean I have a1-a20 and b1-b20. Will there  be several left_join to combine the 20 result them together?